# How can I get my temporary quest follower to stop following me in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Me and my brony, Aela the huntress, went out and attempted to clear a certain cave near Whiterun, destroying the Silver Hand clan to restore honor to our werewolf kind. I was not prepared for the strength of the final adversary, Kelv the Skinner. After many failed attempts to end him, Aela and I fled the cave. Now, I cannot convince her that the quest is to be temporarily postponed, and she follows me, no matter where I go. Can someone suggest a way to remove her from my party? I have already deselected the quest.

This is the PS3 version of Skyrim. Ergo, I cannot go into the system console or whatever and change anything about the game.

Comment: There a reason you don't want an extra bow following you around the dangerous countrysides? Just wondering.

Comment: Yes; I'm part of the dark brotherhood.

Comment: I have died 5 times before killing Kelv the Skinner as well. Stuff that helps: kill his minions first, feed on them to regenerate. Avoid him, let Aela do the damage (he can't kill her, only incapacitate her for a short while). His weapon does major damage, but is slow: avoid his attack, hit him and then back off to avoid again. Hit him multiple times (alternating left-right) to stagger him so he temporarily can't hit you. He is hard, but doable!

Comment: And don't forget your werewolf-shout...

Comment: You could try lowering your difficulty settings if you haven't already.

Comment: Aha! I had the same issue with Kelv... I was in despair until I read that. Shouting makes a world of difference. You can't hit me if you're too busy wetting your pants now.

Comment: Also - if you have Dawnguard - the Cross bow can help significantly.

Answer (score 4):

You accepted to do it, so you should do so. Just get enough potions to survive, and [beat him](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35592/how-can-i-get-a-companion-to-stop-following-me#comment-51949)...

Unless you recover from a save or temper with PS3 data, there is no way out!

Normal companions can stop following you by talking to them and selecting the last option.

Answer (score 0):

She won't stop following you until you complete the quest, I had that problem too. How I beat Kelv was with a Pet Dog, Aela, and an Enchanted bow. He's not too hard, as long as you let Aela and you Dog do the close combat.